# AngularJS: Property 'ngEnter' does not exist on type 'IAttributes'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, webstorm

I'm using Typescript and migrating the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) definitions for angular from 1.3 to [1.6.2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular/index.d.ts) leads to the following error in my `MainModule.ts`:

```
Error:(14, 43) TS2339:Property 'ngEnter' does not exist on type 'IAttributes'.
```

The code that triggers the compiler error is defining the angularjs module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.modal', 'smart-table'])
    .service('appService', AppService)
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .controller('uploadTSCtrl', UploadTSCtrl)
    .controller('inputCtrl', InputCtrl)
    .controller('reportCtrl', ReportCtrl)
    .directive('ngEnter', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                if(event.which === 13) {
                    scope.$apply(function (){
                        scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter); // <<<<<<<<<<<<< here
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        };
    })
```

I could not find a migration guide or anything like it from 1.x to 1.6.2 and don't know how to fix it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered such problems and just made

```
scope.$eval(attrs['ngEnter']);
```

OR

```
scope.$eval((attrs as any).ngEnter);
```

to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I also found another way using a pre-built directive that can just be plugged in for this OP purpose: [typescript-key-enter-directive](https://github.com/jbaroudi/typescript-key-enter-directive)